# how to display image in datagrid cell if value is true

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The WPF form contains a `DataGrid`. One of the columns has values of type `bool`. I would like to display a check sign image if the value of the cell is `true`. How to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display WPF checkboxes, you can use the built-in `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding YourProperty}"/>
```

If you have a custom image and only want to display it when the property is `true` use a template.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourType}">
         <Image x:Name="CheckImage" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Image.Source>
               <BitmapImage UriSource="C:\Path\To\Your\Image.jpg"/>
            </Image.Source>
         </Image>
         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="True">
               <Setter TargetName="CheckImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </DataTemplate.Triggers>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```